# Extract text information from MS Word

Tags: .net, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop, openxml-sdk

i want to extract text information from MS Word document. The extracted information contain position, page number and style of text. Does anyone can suggest me How can i do That? what library can support me to do that?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use OpenXML SDK version 2.0. You can check the blog below to how to know extract content. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/02/16/finding-paragraphs-by-style-name-or-content-in-an-open-xml-word-processing-document.aspx

Or more info about OpeXML SDK:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa905545.aspx

With this library you don't need to install MS Word on your computer to extract content or produce a new Word document.

Hope this help.